# Как передать текст из text в textarea?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Писал, писал, писал.. Но тут наткнулся на то, что мне не в силах реализовать. Нужно учиться.

Вообщем, так получается, что мне нужно текст из

```
input type="text"
```

передать в

```
textarea
```

Как это можно реализовать? Подтолкните, а то я не в силах что либо придумать..

Comment: java или javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('textarea').val($('input').val()); 
или
document.getElementById("textarea").value = document.getElementById("input").value
```